# How to install from source libpng-devel

Tags: linux, installation, libpng

I need to install libpng-devel to support png files in ImageMagik. Where can I find the package?

I have installed libpng-1.6.18 from source and it's working well with other programs but with that installation I don't have the devel headers or libraries. Also, I can't use yum or apt-get in this machine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: usually, `make install` install include files as well as pkgconfig file, can you check it?

Comment: Yes, I have the include files pngconf.h, png.h and pnglibconf.h and libpng.pc under /lib/pkgconfig.

Comment: what is the ouput of `pkg-config --cflags libpng`? it should be the dir where `png.h` is located

Comment: ok, it says: Package libpng was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libpng.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libpng' found. I guess I need to add it to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable

Comment: it should be located in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` you can both copy or symlink it; anyway, you have installed png from sources, which means you installed both `libpng` and `libpng-devel` (which is a little package containing the files you mentioned in your first comment)

Comment: well, png.h is located under /usr/include/libpng16.

Comment: it should be ok, when a program needs to compile against png, it uses pkg-config to get paths and flags, like `-I/usr/include/libpng16` (`pkg-config --cflags libpng`) and `-lpng16` (`pkg-config --libs libpng`)

Comment: I've justed fixed it. I tried adding the PKG_CONFIG_PATH=-I/usr/lib/pkgconfig to the ./configure installation of Imagemagik and work. Thank you very much for your time and help.